# Using Windows Performance Tools for tracing an application running on a remote computer

Tags: performance, trace

How can I trace a system responsiveness and application resource usage issue on a remote computer? I deployed my application(written using unmanaged c++ code) on my client's computer running Windows XP sp3 pro, but its running very slowly and I want to diagnose it since it runs well on my Windows 7 machine. How can i fo it remotely and if thats too difficult how can i do it onsite?

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the bottleneck.

Usually it is either a CPU, disk or memory bottleneck. You can find out this by using [perfmon](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305610) or [sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/default.aspx) tools such as filemon,diskmon, procmon ... These can be left running to gather and store data, although there could be some performance implications.

After you find the bottleneck, you need to see if it is due to anything you are doing or just the machine does not have enough resources ...

There are some profiling tools as well which come with VS and you can use to isolate the problem.

Comment: can i fo it remotely on a xp machine from a win7 machine

Comment: i think the client's machine is too low on CPU resources and as is the case that its hard to convince business people about that

Comment: can i use Event Tracing for Windows tools (if any) instead of sysinternals tools or are the sysinternal tools built on Event Tracing for Windows

Comment: Get perfmon to record CPU usage and store on a file. You can see spikes in there. You can call those API from within your code but I am not sure what you get extra on the top of perfmon.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use XPerf against Windows XP, sorry :(